# Create a class that inherits from UITextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In my app I need to create a self made property to the `UITextField` that registers whether the user has "used" the textfield or not. What I mean by "used" is whether the user has typed something or not. For various reasons I cannot use `textfield.text.isEmpty`.

Anyone know how this can be done?

I have tried creating a class named `Textfield` that inherits from `UITextField`, and then connecting an outlet of type `Textfield`, instead of type `UITextField`. Like this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textfieldOne: Textfield!
```

But whenever I try to change the "used" value by clicking on a button or whatever, the app crashes.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the crash

Comment: If the app is crashing then it will post a crash log. Please copy and paste that into your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set custom class for your uitextfield in interface builder as well

[image]